# jquery tooltip problems on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-tooltip

I am a novice in Jquery and trying to implement Jquery tooltip to pop up phone number of a resturant

First i was trying to put it in my MENU BAR and was failed to implement it, you can see it in my page scripting code...
Then i tried to put in on 3 places on the page and having problems a lot, my nivoslider goes away when i hover on one of my SUBMIT NOW Button

Just click the SUBMIT NOW button and see for your self
here is the link for the page 
[Click HERE](http://www.coffeedesign.net/test/index2.html)

Comment: Restaurant - You're missing the first A in the spelling.

Comment: Please consider bringing the relevant code (sufficient to demonstrate your problem, html *and* jQuery) into the question. Also, a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be useful, as it allows us to play with the code to isolate the problem(s).

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine your `$(document).ready(function(){});` calls into one (I counted at least two in your source-code) and put `$(".download_now").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});` into it. If you still have problems, you should look into using [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), particularly for Nivo Slider. You should ideally not be mixing `$(document).ready(function(){});` and `$(window).ready(function(){});` either.

Comment: i am still not able to do anything, when i use noconflict, everything stop working even the hover menu stop working